# Excel: Adding to numeric ID in response to string

Tags: excel

I hope I posed the question correctly. To be more specific, I have one column that has an alphanumeric ID (Bxxx or Sxxx) which I am hoping to use to track Buy and Sell activities. The adjacent column, accordingly, will have either "Buy" or "Sell" in it.

My question is, is it possible to automatically assign the next alphanumeric ID based on a new Buy or Sell activity? In other words, if my last transaction is a Buy with ID B123, and I write "Buy" in the next row, can the adjacent column automatically fill in B124?

I'm thinking something like "if(Column B) = Buy, "B"+"(Column A number + 1)"

Obviously that's poor syntax but I hope it gets the idea across.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: You can use `XLOOKUP()` then add 1 with last found value.

Answer (score 1):

If your first figure (B1 or S1) is manually entered into cell A2 then this will work in cell A3 onwards.

```
=LEFT($B3,1) & MAX(VALUE(IF(LEFT($A$2:$A2,1)=LEFT($B3,1),MID($A$2:$A2,2,LEN($A$2:$A2)),0)))+1
```

The formula will count Buy & Sell separately.  So you'll get B1 & S1.